# Assigning value to a string in Power Query

Tags: excel, if-statement, powerbi, powerquery

I have the following code:

```
let
    Condition = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="test_table"]}[Content],
    field = Condition{0}[field_excel],  
    str = "One",
    query = if field <> null
        then str = "two" 
        else str = "three",
    exec= Oracle.Database("TESTING", [Query=str])
in
    exec
```

I want to depending the condition `str` have the value of `two` or `three`, but always stays with  `One`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do something like this:

```
...
field = Condition{0}[field_excel],
str   = if field <> null then "two" else "three",
exec  = Oracle.Database("TESTING", [Query = str]),
...
```

Power Query does not let you reassign values to a variable in a let expression. Instead, you would assign the value to a new variable.